# How to Find Selected Node PortalSiteMapDataSource

Tags: 2007, navigation, publishing

I am trying to Create Custom Navigation control which read Nodes from given PortalSiteMapDataSourceID and generate XML and then use XSLT to generate HTML out of it.How can i find selected node from DataSourceID so i can add one more XML selected = true ? 
Please advise

Thanks 
Ronak

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example is complicated, so I'm not sure that it is the best way in you case )

```
ProviderSettings settings = new ProviderSettings("GlobalNavSiteMapProvider", "Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Navigation.PortalSiteMapProvider, Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c");
settings.Parameters["NavigationType"] = PortalNavigationType.Current.ToString();
settings.Parameters["EncodeOutput"] = "true";

PortalSiteMapProvider provider = (PortalSiteMapProvider)ProvidersHelper.InstantiateProvider(settings, typeof(PortalSiteMapProvider));
PortalSiteMapNode currentNode = (PortalSiteMapNode)provider.CurrentNode;
```

Comment: Thanks Alexander it helps to give me direction and achieve what i want.

Comment: I have a [post](http://akrupsky.blogspot.com/2012/01/cross-site-collection-navigation.html) that describes how to implement cross site collection navigation control. There are a litle explanation how to Portal site map provider works. I hope it will be helpful to undrestand what you wants to implement.